# Rider file templates for UWP projects

Tags: templates, uwp, jetbrains-ide, rider

JetBrains Rider does not have file templates for UWP Projects (`Page.xaml`, `ResourceDictionary.xaml`, `UserControl.xaml` etc.)

I've tried to create the custom file template for UWP (Xaml (C#)) such as `Page.xaml`, but the associated code-behind class doesn't generate as well.

How can I create a `Page.xaml` file template with generating an associated code-behind class?

I'm using JetBrains Rider 2022.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I research this question and found that the JetBrains Rider doesn't have this feature now.

Who is interested, [YourTrack JetBrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-62037/Create-Views-from-Project-View-in-UWP)